# Checking correspondences between cities and postcodes in R

Tags: r

I have a database with addresses (`df`) and a database of all the existing postcodes in France (`cp`). I am trying to check if a postcode/city couple in `df` is correct according to the postcode database.

The main issue I'm facing is the many-to-many relationship of the data. Basically, a city can have multiple postcodes and different cities can be in the same postcode area. For example, these cities are causing a problem :

```
        cp$city      cp$postcode
AIX EN PROVENCE            13080
AIX EN PROVENCE            13090
AIX EN PROVENCE            13100
AIX EN PROVENCE            13290
AIX EN PROVENCE            13540
BEAURECUEIL                13100
ST MARC JAUMEGARDE         13100
LE THOLONET                13100
```

As you can see, Aix en Provence has five different postcodes and 13100 covers four different cities.

I have been trying the following code to see whether a couple is correct or not :

```
df$city == cp$city[match(df$postcode, cp$postcode)]
```

But it's returning that the couple `13100 LE THOLONET` is false. I'm pretty sure this piece of code would be fine if each city had a single code, and each code matched a single city. What can I do to adjust it to the many-to-many cardinality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this maybe:

```
cp = data.frame(city=c(rep("AIX EN PROVENCE",5),"BEAURECUEIL","ST MARC JAUMEGARDE","LE THOLONET"),postcode=c(13080,13090,13100,13290,13540,13100,13100,13100))
df = data.frame(city=c(rep("AIX EN PROVENCE",4),"BEAURECUEIL","LE THOLONET","PARIS","MARSEILLE"),postcode=c(13080,13090,13100,13540,13100,13100,75014,13001))


df$correct<-paste0(df$city,df$postcode) %in% paste0(cp$city,cp$postcode)

>df
             city postcode correct
1 AIX EN PROVENCE    13080    TRUE
2 AIX EN PROVENCE    13090    TRUE
3 AIX EN PROVENCE    13100    TRUE
4 AIX EN PROVENCE    13540    TRUE
5     BEAURECUEIL    13100    TRUE
6     LE THOLONET    13100    TRUE
7           PARIS    75014   FALSE
8       MARSEILLE    13001   FALSE
```

Comment: Similarly with a data.table join, `library(data.table); setDT(cp); setDT(df); df[, found := cp[df, on=.(city, postcode), .N, by=.EACHI]$N > 0L][]`

Comment: or this:
`df$correct <- TRUE; df <- merge(df,cp,by=c("city","postcode),all.x= TRUE); df$correct[is.na(df$correct)] <- FALSE`